# data:, shown in the chrome url bar when I execute the following Selenium ChromeWebdrive Script

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, socketexception

data:, shown in the chrome url bar when I execute the following Selenium ChromeWebdrive Script. Is the because other instance of chrome browser are working?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ChromWebdriverWindows {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //String url = "https://www.google.co.in/";
        System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Automation\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver drive;
        drive = new ChromeDriver();
        drive.get("https://www.flock.co");
    }

}
```

Getting this error in console:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067) on port 7264
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17 -0800'
System info: host: 'MDVLFARZANS', ip: '192.168.0.106', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:178)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:124)
    at ChromWebdriverWindows.main(ChromWebdriverWindows.java:10)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:155)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:296)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Update Chrome and the Selenium packages and try again

Comment: @JeffC My chrome is updated to Version 57.0.2987.133 also my selenium Package is the latest one i.e 3.3.1

Comment: What about Chrome Driver version?

Comment: @JeffC using the latest chrome driver version tooi.e 2.29

Comment: Getting this error in console

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17 -0800'
System info: host: 'MDVLFARZANS', ip: '192.168.0.106', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine just replace `.getProperty()` with `.setProperty()`:

```
System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
  "C:\\Automation\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
```

with

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
  "C:\\Automation\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: hey, this worked, Moved the driver to the selenium untility folder. Thanks alot